# how to fix my code to conver xlsx to pdf in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, format

i have this code for convering my excel file to pdf but after changing format, i have a  pdf file with lots of pages(in every page just 4 coumns with 19 rows while my source file has 30 columns and rows , i want to see same as excel file but in pdf format , any body can  help me! thanks in advance

```
 Sub creatpdf()


 Dim fName As String
 Dim fname1 As String

 With Worksheets("Output_" & Date)
 fName2 = .Range("D3").Value
 fName3 = "_BOM"
 End With

 BrowseForFolder = "X:\\output\\"

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        BrowseForFolder & "\" & fName2 & fName3 & "\" & "\" & fName2 &            fName3 & "\" & "BOM" & "\" & fName2 & fName3, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, 
 OpenAfterPublish:=False

 End Sub
```

Comment: Check the path and name of the file. You are adding too many slashes.

Comment: may check your excel files print setup

Comment: "X:\\output\" <- one slash after directory, two after Drive, this is also likely a problem & "\" & "\" & as it is again a double slash.